# how to solve the following quadratic word problem *updated*?

Tags: quadratics

The total cost of carpeting a rectangular room is given the expression
$$6x^2 + 18x$$
Which situation *best* describes the expression?

1. The length of the room is  **6+2x** feet, its width is **2x** feet, and the cost of carpeting is **$1.50**per square foot.
2. The length of the room is **3 + 2x** feet, its width is **2x** feet and the cost of carpentering is **$3.00** per square foot
3. The area of the floor is $$4x^2 + 9x$$  square feet, and the cost of carpeting is  **$1.50** per square foot.
4. The area of the floor is $$ 2x^2 + 9x$$ square feet, and the cost of carpeting is  **$3.00** per square foot.

The first thing I did to try to solve this was I factored it so
$$6x(x + 3)$$ 
so area is found by doing ***L * W*** so which one would be the length **6x** or **(x+3)**. Cause I mean it can be anyone of these. Which is the correct answer from the given? and also could you explain why?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the first situation $$(6+2x)\times (2x)\times 1.5=6 x^2+18 x$$ Consider the second situation $$(3+2x)\times (2x)\times 3=12 x^2+18 x$$ Consider the third situation $$(4x^2+9x)\times 1.5=6 x^2+\frac{27 }{2}x$$ Consider the fourth situation $$(2x^2+9x)\times 3=6 x^2+27 x$$ Hoping no mistake.

For this kind of problem, just consider the different cases; may be two (or more) could be equivalent.

## Happy New Year !!

Comment: Happy new year, lol i can't believe i didn't think about that